# string passed through php always has spaces translated to + signs. How to decode correctly?

Tags: php, javascript, json, urlencode

I hava json string that's getting appended to a url and then put into a php cookie.

```
//redirect url with short json string appended
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.location = \"site/temp_process.php?ui=". urlencode(json_encode($user_information)) ." \";</script>";//$user_information is php assoc. array


$user_information = urldecode($_REQUEST['ui']); //user information

setcookie('isco', $user_information, time()+60*60*24*30);
```

Then read the cookie with [this javascript function](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html):

```
cookie = readCookie("isco");
cookie = decodeURIComponent(cookie);


function readCookie(name) {  
    var cookiename = name + "=";  
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');  
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++){  
        var c = ca[i];  
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);  
        if (c.indexOf(cookiename) == 0) return c.substring(cookiename.length,c.length);  
    }  
    return null;  
}
```

But no matter if I remove the javascript `decodeURIComponent` or switch the php `urlencode/urldecode` `rawurlencode/rawurldecode`, I'm still getting spaces that appear as `+` signs. How can I avoid this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Generally you don't have to `urldecode($_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST);`. Have you `var_dump()` your `$_REQUEST['ui']` to make sure that you do NEED TO decode it?

Comment: @Passerby Yeah, when I echo a `var_dump()` before it is saved as a cookie it prints to the screen with normal (non-encoded)spaces. But still has the plus signs after it is read from the cookie and printed to the screen..

Comment: Cookies STRING have to be encoded for the "safety" of transferring; but the INFORMATION/DATA is not encoded for either side. You may want to remove the `urldecode` on server (PHP) side, and, reading [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie#A_little_framework.3A_a_complete_cookies_reader.2Fwriter_with_full_unicode_support), use `unescape` to "decode" it.